# Adding data/values to shp produces error. Whats wrong?

Tags: r, polygon, shapefile, tmap

I'm trying to use library(tmap) to color regions after some value (like income).
I have a shp-file for Sweden and some incomedata in a xlsx-file.

First I import the data:

```
map <- readOGR("Kommun_RT90_region.shp", encoding = "UTF-8")
kapital_kommun <- read_xlsx("kapital_edit2.xlsx")
```

This is how the map@data looks like:

```
KnKod         KnNamn
0  0114 Upplands Väsby
1  0115     Vallentuna
2  0117      Österåker
3  0120         Värmdö
4  0123       Järfälla
5  0125          Ekerö
```

KnKod is the official key for each region and KnNamn is the name of the region. If I run the following code I get a map of Sweden with a unique color for each 290 regions:

```
tm_shape(map) + tm_fill("KnKod") + tm_borders()
```

[image: Heres what the map looks like]
The trouble starts when I add the info from my xlsx file to the shp-file:

```
map <- merge(map, kapital_kommun, by = "KnKod")

KnKod         KnNamn medel_finans_kapital
1  0114 Upplands Väsby               125573
2  0115     Vallentuna                56361
3  0117      Österåker                93963
4  0120         Värmdö                67308
5  0123       Järfälla                32321
6  0125          Ekerö               102685
```

This looks fine to me but now I get a error when I run the previous code and no map/plot is drawn. I've tried both "KnKod" and "medel_finans_kapital":

```
tm_shape(map) + tm_fill("KnKod") + tm_borders()

> tm_shape(map) + tm_fill("KnKod") + tm_borders()
Error in st_as_sfc.SpatialPolygons(sp::geometry(x), ...) : 
  package rgeos required for finding out which hole belongs to which exterior ring
In addition: Warning message:
In sp::proj4string(obj) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

Seems like adding the medel_finans_kapital column "breaks" code somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
Instead of:
 map <- merge(map, kapital_kommun, by = "KnKod")
 I used:
 map$income <- kapital_kommun$medel_finans_kapital

Now I can plot the a map. Why it made a difference I have no idea. The outcome looks the same - both columns look the same and are labeled as "num".

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a more reproducible example of your problem. It is difficult to find what is wrong just from reading the code.

I thinke the problem is when you use the **merge()** function, do you still have an *sp* object after that?

Alsop please notice that *sp* definition is now being deprecated in favour of *sf*. Also, with *sf* you can use standrad **tidyverse** funtions. Son instead of **merge** you can use somthing like **left_join**.

I recommend you to take a look at a my notes from a worksop: https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/

It is not updated since last year, but it should still be functional.